# Python 2.7.13 cannot import ArcPy in ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, arcgis-10.5

I am using ArcGIS 10.5.1 and Python 2.7.13. I have also ArcGIS Pro on the same computer. Our license is in network server in our company.

**Import arcpy is currently not working.**

I had some tools to process shapefile and do some calculations and I have also implemented Tkinter GUI. It worked before. Suddenly it stops working, it cannot import ArcPy any more and automatically terminates the program without showing any error message.

```
RESTART: C:\Users\SPervin\Desktop\Tools_Biotop_FFH_berechnung\Biotop_berechnung_tkinter.py 
RESTART: Shell 
import arcpy
RESTART: Shell
```

**It is just terminating the the process.**

Example screenshot for system paths:
[image]

Comment: That ArcGIS Technical Report titled [Unable to import arcpy](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012334) may help.

Comment: what version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I have windows 10

Comment: @Kadir it was a nice recommendation. But It is working for every earlier version but only not in ArcGIS 10.5.1